# How to call an external function inside onbeforeunload() if the user chooses to move out of the page?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, onunload

I've seen many examples and tried them out where the specified function gets called if the user decides to stay in the page. 
I need to call an external function just before the page is unloaded, if the user decides to leave the page.

```
onbeforeunload = function(){
  if(user decides to leave the page){
      func1();
  }
  else {
    //Don't do anything
  }
}
```

I tried using "onunload" but I need to prompt the user before calling the function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not possible. The user doesn't answer the prompt until *after* the function returns.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the info! Do you know if there's a workaround for this? Or some other way of achieving this?

Comment: Why doesn't `onunload` work? Use `onbeforeunload` to return a prompt string, and if the user decides to leave `onunload` will be triggered.

Comment: Don't call `confirm()`, just call `func1()`. The user has already confirmed that they want to leave because of the `onbeforeunload` function.

Comment: @Barmar prompts, confirms and alerts are blocked inside onbeforeunload.

Comment: I know that. That's why you have to use `onbeforeunload` to display a confirmation.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry if it's a noob question but can you tell me what you mean by "return a prompt string"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use both `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.onunload`. `onbeforeunload` returns a string, and this causes the browser to display a confirmation before leaving. If the user confirms leaving, `onunload` will be triggered, and then you do what you need before the page is unloaded.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
};
window.onunload = function() {
    func1();
};
```

There are restrictions on what you can do in both of these event handlers, because you're not allowed to prevent the user from leaving the page if they really want to. Malware used to use these events to do things like reopening the page, now this is prohibited.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! This makes a lot of sense logically. It wasn't working when I tried it, though. I realized that it might be because the `func1()` has async calls and the page is getting unloaded before it can make the appropriate updates in the database and return.
Any thoughts on how I could solve this?

Comment: That's right. You might need to use something like webworkers for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into using webworkers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run some custom code before the user leaves the page, if `beforeunload` doesn't work for you because the browser navigates away before your code is run you can instead add a `mouseleave` event listener to the `document`. If the user's mouse leaves the document it's very likely they are leaving your page (to either close the page, change tabs, use another program on their computer, etc).

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
 console.log('mouse left the document');
 // your code or function here
});
```

Try running the above snippet and moving your mouse in & out of the result  box.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, nice thinking. But I'm trying to solve this particular case so the `mouseleave` event won't help me.